# Multilevel hierarchy with virtuality prevents casting function pointers

Tags: c++, casting, pointer-to-member

I've created some class hierarchy, of which base class (in the following example: `clA`) defines function pointers that are called from `executor` routine. In turn, code that is passed `executor` as a callback, does not know on which type of derived object it operates (`clB` is only one of them). If a derived class does not implement some functions it doesn't cast to function pointer and nothing happens when `executor` is called. There's also some virtual functions (`clA` is actually pure virtual). My classess look similar to this (can't present actual code, so I created simplified demo):

```
class clA
{
protected:
    INT_PTR(__stdcall clA::*Fn1)(int);
    INT_PTR(__stdcall clA::*Fn2)(int);
    static INT_PTR CALLBACK executor(UINT operation, int opData, clA *ptr = NULL)
    {
        switch (operation)
        {
        case 1:
            if (ptr->Fn1)
            {
                typedef INT_PTR(__stdcall clA::*FPtr)(int);
                FPtr funcPtr = ptr->Fn1;
                return (ptr->*funcPtr)(opData);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (ptr->Fn2)
            {
                typedef INT_PTR(__stdcall clA::*FPtr)(int);
                FPtr funcPtr = ptr->Fn2;
                return (ptr->*funcPtr)(opData);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
public:
    clA() { Fn1 = NULL; Fn2 = NULL; }
    virtual BOOL vrt(void) = 0;
};

class clB : public clA
{
    INT_PTR __stdcall ImplFn1(int) { return 0; }
    INT_PTR __stdcall ImplFn2(int) { return 0; }
public:
    void testing(void);
    clB()
    {
        Fn1 = reinterpret_cast <INT_PTR(__stdcall clA::*)(int)> (&clB::ImplFn1);
        Fn2 = reinterpret_cast <INT_PTR(__stdcall clA::*)(int)> (&clB::ImplFn2);
    }
    BOOL vrt(void) { return FALSE; };
};
```

Everything worked up until now, only today I decided I needed base class `clA` to inherit from some other class, let it be `clExtra`, so I made following changes:

```
class clExtra
{
public:
   static int x;
};

//now class clA is deriving from clExtra
class clA : public clExtra
```

**The Problem**

Now I have the following compile error:

```
inheritancetest.h(49): error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'INT_PTR (__stdcall clB::* )(int)' to 'INT_PTR (__stdcall clA::* )(int)'
Pointers to members have different representations; cannot cast between them
```

I honestly do not understand how they're suddenly became *different representations*. MSDN's examples of possible C2440 causes do not apply. Weird thing is that I can ALSO make it compile if I remove any virtuality from `clA` class. If anyone understands what may be causing my inability to cast I'll be forever grateful for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's bug in VC++. It [compiles successfully](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b5ed6c3db945722) in gcc.

`static_cast` is sufficient for this type of conversion.

I discovered that VC++ won't complain when using `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: You're actually right, I could replace all casts with `static_cast`, but I wanted to avoid it since there's so many of them... It will still be faster to rework 1000 constructors than to wait for possible confirmation of a bug, though. I'll get to it, meanwhile maybe someone else with similar experience reads this post

Comment: @Kitet Why don't you want to use `static_cast`? Performance? I think that in this case no extra instructions will be inserted as they're not needed. If you want to be 100% sure take a look at generated assembly.

Comment: You must have misunderstood something. I switched all of them to static, took 2 hours for all the constructors and some testing.